# How to find with 'OR' in mongoosejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How would I use an 'OR' selector in mongoosejs?
Say in the below example, I would not only want to find `Ghost` but also `Ghost2`. I could call findOne twice, but I think this might be less efficient, if there are many other fields present.

```
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', yourSchema);

// find each person with a last name matching 'Ghost', selecting the `name` and `occupation` fields
Person.findOne({ 'name.last': 'Ghost' }, 'name occupation', function (err, person) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log('%s %s is a %s.', person.name.first, person.name.last, person.occupation) // Space Ghost is a talk show host.
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it in the docs. The `$or` operator accomplishes this:

```
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', yourSchema);

// find each person with a last name matching 'Ghost', selecting the `name` and `occupation` fields
Person.findOne({'$or': [{ 'name.last': 'Ghost1' }, {'name.last': 'Ghost2' }], 'name occupation', function (err, person) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log('%s %s is a %s.', person.name.first, person.name.last, person.occupation) // Space Ghost is a talk show host.
})
```